# please enter a valid value the two nearest valid value is?

Tags: javascript, html

my assignment is to make weight calculator but due to limitations of university I am not able to use all tags so I write code it works fine but gives me a error of `please enter a valid value the two nearest valid value are ***number*** and ***number***`.

I think that is because of the *number* attribute in *input* tag but I can not able to find what's wrong and how to correct it.

There is one more error if I only calculate one conversion output flash on screen and vanished if I get output in all fields then answer is shown.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Weight Convertor Calculator</title>
  <script>
    var z;
    var x;

    function converter() {
      if (document.weight.kg.value >= 1) {
        x = document.weight.kg.value;
        document.getElementById("g").value = x * 1000;
        document.getElementById("p").value = x * 2.2046;
        document.getElementById("m").value = x * 1000000;
        document.getElementById("ut").value = x * 0.0011023;
        z = 35.274 * x;
        document.getElementById("o").value = z;

      } else {
        window.alert("please enter any number greater than 0");
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#b3f0ff">
  <h1 align="center" style="color:#ff0066;"> Weight Calculator</h1>
  <br>
  <br>
  <form name="weight" method="post">
    <table align="center" style="color:#ff0066;">
      <tr>
        <td><b>Enter your weight in Kg:</b></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="kg" name="kilogram" placeholder="enter_any_number"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right"><input type="submit" value="Convert" onClick="converter(kg.value)"></td>
        <td><input type="reset"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>weight in Grams=</b></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="g" name="gram"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>weight in Pounds=</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="p" name="pound"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>weight in MilliGrams=</b></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="m" name="milligram"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>weight in US Ton=</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="ut" name="uton"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>weight in Ounces=</b></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="o" name="ounce"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form><br>
  <p align="center" style="color:#ff0066;"><b>NOTE: Enter only numerical 
      value which is greater than 0</b></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In number inputs fragments are not allowed, so you need to use an text input.
2. Your form will be submitted: data gone

Here you can find a [demo](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FONIXMJKQ0WI) that works, based on your code.

Comment: It's not necessary to use a text input. What does "data gone" mean?

Answer (score 168):

Try adding the attribute `step="any"` to your `input`. That helped me.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Relevant documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#step

Comment: I had this issue with the datetimepicker and this suggestion fixed it.

Comment: Can't believe I've been making websites for a decade and didn't know this... god this feels so dumb... Thank you so much

Answer (score 11):

No need to make input type 'text', just add one attribute step="0.01" with type="number" to accept decimal values.

Answer (score -2):

Changing input typ from number to text will work.

Comment: but I need numbers only.

Comment: setting `type='text'` is a work around but does not answer the question using `step='any'` is the best way.

Comment: if you need to use `number`, you can add `title=""` to override the browser's default